# No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type from content with media type 'text/html'

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.0

Running Core 2.0 Web Api. Everything works fine locally when I post via Postman to my controller. However I get:

> No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Message'
>   from content with media type 'text/html'

When deployed to production server

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromQuery] Message message)
    {
        _service.UserRequest(message);
    }
```

Message:

```
public class Message : IEntity
{
    public string To { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string From { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Body { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Not sure what's causing this. Is it mime types in IIS configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed it (Added new Formatters):

```
        var obj = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>(
            new List<MediaTypeFormatter>
            {
                new XmlMediaTypeFormatter(),
                new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried this variant of the previous answer with the goal of tightening up the code:

```
var obj = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>( new [] { new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() });
```

However, it still complained for me since the response still didn't have the correct content header.

So, I tried this to change the headers, which works for me, but I really don't know if this has any unexpected side effects that I just haven't thought through yet:

```
if(response.Content?.Headers?.ContentType != null)
{
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "application/json";
}
```